# DOMException while decrypting RSA data

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, rsa, webcrypto-api

I'm trying to send encrypted data from server to client and decrypt it by using `window.crypto.subtle.decrypt()`. But i've got an Error without description. How can i fix it?

node.js server code:

```js
const sharedKey = (req, res, next) => {
  let crypto = require('crypto');

  let buf = Buffer.from('Hello, my friend');

  const key = {
    key: req.body.public,
    padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING
  }

  try {
    let encrypted = crypto.publicEncrypt(key, buf);
    res.send(encrypted.toString('base64'));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('err', err)
  }
};
```

client code:

```js
$.post('/register', {
  'login': login,
  'public': publicKeyPEM
}, function(data) {
  console.log('data', data);
  data = Ocrypto.base64ToArrayBuffer(data);
  try {
    window.crypto.subtle.decrypt({
          name: "RSA-OAEP",
          //label: Uint8Array([...]) //optional
        },
        keyPair.privateKey, //from generateKey or importKey above
        data //ArrayBuffer of the data
      )
      .then(function(decrypted) {
        //returns an ArrayBuffer containing the decrypted data
        console.log(new Uint8Array(decrypted));
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("ERRRRRR", err);
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('err', err)

  }
});
```

That what i've got in console: "ERRRRRR DOMException"

Answer (score 0):

```
data = Ocrypto.base64ToArrayBuffer(data);
```

Seems like you have a typo there.

Comment: What browser are you testing on? Also, I'd recommend logging your key and data before calling decrypt so you can see if you are providing valid parameters.

Comment: chrome. U mean: use `window.crypto.subtle.importKey` before `decrypt`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to solve that problem, but i found another way how to do mu project works. 
I use [node-rsa](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rsa) on server, and on client after buildin by [browserify](http://browserify.org/)